# Могу ли я поставить тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Возможна ли в данной конструкции между "спеть красиво" и "я могу" постановка тире, если я мысленно вставлю слово "это"?

> Спеть красиво — (это) я могу.

Answer (score 1):

***Спеть красиво (?) (это) я могу.***

В простом предложении постановка тире выглядит **некорректно**, так что "мысленные подстановки" здесь не помогут.

А вот **в сложном** предложении это возможно, например: ***СпЕть красиво — я могу**, но вообще в музыке разбираюсь плОхо.*

В этом предложении логическое ударение делается на первом слове, что дает возможность для естественного обозначения паузы.

Comment: Sharon, лучше, наверно, написать "в *простом* предложении...".

Comment: Да, спасибо, я исправила.

Answer (score 0):

Спеть красиво? - Я могу. (!)
Я бы оформил так.